# Profile photo - twitter

Tags: tails, html5

how do you change the profile photo in twitter on tails? It tells me when I try that - the website is trying to extract HTML 5 canvas data that can uniquely identify my computer, how do I get around this without violating my security?

Answer (score 2):

The pop-up you're talking about comes from Tor Browser. If you choose *Not now* (or even choose never for this site), this method of fingerprinting is stopped.

Besides that you can just easily change your profile photo.

1. Log in to Twitter
2. Go to your profile
3. Choose "edit profile"
4. Choose another photo
5. Save your changes
6. win :-).

Answer (score 1):

I would get a prepaid android phone and change your photo on the twitter app you download on the phone. Then delete app and never use phone again. Probably smash it into tiny pieces and throw into the river. You can pickup a crappy Huawei Android phone for around $40 that includes some prepaid minutes of data or connect to a public wifi. Hope that helps.

Comment: Note: throwing pieces of a phone in a river might not be environmentally friendly ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to hate me for asking this, as it's not even answering the question, but I have a related problem - how did you even sign up for Twitter via Tor? When I try to do it, I am asked to give a phone number for verification, there is no link to skip like in Firefox, and if you use the skip link URL you are forcibly redirected back to the phone verification page. What do you do?